# Undefined response from a fetch request for a mono object from spring boot back end

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, fetch-api

I am trying to make a get request from the client side to the server to get a mono of a shift object but I get my data as undefined. Below is my code.

Client Side

```
function getShift (ID: String) {
    
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/shifts/?ID=" + "shiftID", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          response.json();
        }
      )
      .then((data) => console.log(data, "this is the data"))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Server Side

```
@GetMapping (produces = "application/json")
    private Mono<ResponseEntity<Shift>>  getShift(String ID) {
         return  shiftService.getShift(ID).map(u->ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(u));      
    }
```

Comment: `return response.json()`

Comment: and btw. you will always literally request `http://localhost:8080/shifts/?ID=shiftID`

Comment: Yeh the shiftID was just for question purposes. Also returning response.json() did not work :( and I get this error now "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: Well, it solved the original problem of `data`  being `undefined`.  Seems your backend is returning invalid json. Check the response body in the browser's developer tools ...